# Codeigniter using associative array in Email class

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, email

I have a certain associative array which contains a list of emails. It's given below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => mattfairburne@hotmail.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [email] => velazquez.alvaro@gmail.com
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [email] => pstangerson_1968@gmail.com
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [email] => anuj.galgotia@gmail.com
        )

)
```

It's being generated from the following controller code:

```
$data['list_of_emails'] = $this->Trainee_requisition->get_list_of_emails($id);
```

And the corresponding model code from where the `get_list_of_emails($id)` method is being accessed:

```
function get_list_of_emails($id){
        $q = $this->db->query("SELECT `email` FROM `requisition_emails` WHERE `req_id` = $id")->result_array();
        return $q;
}
```

In the Codeigniter documentations, I've found a way of passing a single dimensional array in the `$this->mail->to()` method of the Email class, but there is no example of an associative array.

My question is, how can I use the above mentioned associative array in the `$this->email->to()` method?

My main objective is to generate something like this:

```
$email_list = array('mattfairburne@gmail.com', 'velazquez_alvaro@gmail.com', 'pstangerson_1968@gmail.com', 'anuj.galgotia@gmail.com');
$this->email->to($email_list);
```

**Edit:**

Although [Hassaan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4939819/hassaan)'s answer is the easiest solution and meets my need perfectly, I'd still appreciate answers which can provide a way to retrieve only one column from a query which has more than one column.

For example, if my query is modified like this:

```
$q = $this->db->query("SELECT rem.`email`, sr.`is_approve` AS approval_status FROM `requisition_emails` rem INNER JOIN `staff_requisitions` sr ON sr.`id` = rem.`req_id` WHERE rem.`req_id` = $id")->result_array();
```

but I want only `email` column to be used from the list, then what is the best possible way?

**Edit - 2:**

Forgot to mention. PHP version is 5.3.

Comment: This is comment after you edited the question. In order to retreive only one column of an array comming from your model, use array_column function, which I used in my answer.

Comment: Ah man finally :) Look at updated answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `foreach` loop in your view.

Try Example

```
foreach($list_of_emails as $email)
{
    echo $email."<br />";
    // You can call '$this->mail->to()' to mail.
}
```

Comment: I've already used your method, but mail is only sent to the last id, i.e. `anuj.galgotia@gmail.com` and not to the others.

Comment: Thanks mate, it's working. The problem was in my further code, I used a `die()`. That's why, email was always being sent to only one address. Also, I had to put the `$this->email->send()` inside the `foreach()`.

Comment: Mate, is it possible for you to update your answer? I have updated my question and looking for yet another small enhancement.

Answer (score 2):

As per CI documentation, you can send email to multiple recipients using the following construction:

```
$this->email->to('one@example.com, two@example.com, three@example.com');
```

In order to generate this kind of string, do following steps:

Don't touch your model

Use PHP `implode` and `array_column` functions to extract `email` field and to concat all array elements by comma:

```
$data['list_of_emails']=$this->Trainee_requisition->get_list_of_emails($id);//Get data from model as one dimensional string
$email_list = implode(',',array_column($data['list_of_emails'],'email'));//Implode array elements with comma as separator
$this->email->to($email_list);
```

You can print `$email_list` to ensure you have right format by calling `var_dump($email_list); exit;`.

### EDIT (If you are using PHP < 5.5)

Use `array_map` function, and make the first parameter as anyonimus function. By defining `$columnName`, you can extract any column you want.

```
 $columnName = "email";
$result = array_map(
    function ($arrayRow) use ($columnName){
        return $arrayRow[$columnName];
    }
,$data['list_of_emails']);
var_dump(implode(",",$result));
$this->email->to($result );
```

Comment: In my question, for convenience I've fetched only one column in my query. What if I re-write my query so that it returns more than one column? How can I fetch `email` then?

Comment: Update is there, please check and try!

Comment: I'm testing. I'll let you now later. Thanks!

Comment: `array_column()` doesn't work for PHP versions earlier than 5.5 . Mine is 5.3.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `array_column` as

```
$new_array = array_column('email');
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work!

```
<?php  $array = array(array("email" => "mattfairburne@hotmail.com"), array("email" => "velazquez.alvaro@gmail.com")); $emailList = array_map('current', $array); print_r($emailList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be solve your problem.

```
$query->result_array();
```

it will gives single dimensional array

Comment: I think you didn't see my question properly. I've used `result_array()` method in my model code.